# When solving PDEs is there an alternative to interpolation for out-of-grid point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm numerically solving a PDE where the space domain is huge.
So, I often need to interpolate to get out-of-grid points needed by the finite difference algorithm.
As a result, I've a lot of numerical instability and the computation of the fixed point of my system takes a lot of time. Each iteration in the fixed point search requiring to solve numerically my PDE.

Is there a way to remove these interpolation errors? As interpolation is kind of brute force, I was wondering if it is possible to get an exact expression for out-of-grid points.
To explain what I'm asking, let's consider the heat equation
\begin{align}
u_{x,x} + u_{y,y} &= f, \\
\left. u \right|_{\partial D} &= 0.
\end{align}
If the $y$-domain is huge and I always need to interpolate there.
Is it a feasible strategy to determine $u_y$, so that, instead of interpolating, 
I do a Taylor approximation
$$
u(x,y_{out})=u(x,y_{grid}) + u_y(x,y_{grid})(y_{out}-y_{grid}),
$$
where $y_{out}$ is an out-of-grid point, and $y_{grid}$ is a grid point.

One technique I know, to avoid interpolation, is something called *similarity* transformation of a PDE. Doing it with the heat equation, this technique is possible when
$$
u(ax,ay)= au(x,y),
$$
so that the $y$-domain is removed by writing
$$
u(x,y) = \frac{y}{y^*}u(x\frac{y^*}{y},y^*).
$$
But this technique is not applicable to all problem.
Are there other such techniques?

Comment: (1) $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$ is Laplace's equation, not heat. (2) More to the point, I think you would more likely get an answer at [scicomp.se]. A moderator can migrate the question there if you want.